# Center Div in Bootstrap Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I center my `div` inside a separate `div` with a class `footer navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom` in bootstrap? Here's my exact code.

```
<div class="footer navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="center-block">
        <div class="small navbar-text text-center">
            First Line<br />
            Second Line<br />
            Third Line
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Image in Fullscreen:**

[image]

But if I resize the width of my browser, the position is fine.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.navbar-text` was floating to the left.

[Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6811/) it for ya :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. [I was wondering if this is the same with solution here?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/114549/1204929)

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` should be enough to center anything, the issue you were having was that there was a floating rule which overrides any margins. so look out for those.